# How to pass class/structure instances as arguments to callbacks using boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I am looking for and stuck on issue of passing class and structure instances  as arguments to call back functions using `boost::bind`

So far call back using [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191299/Secure-Function-Pointer-and-Callbacks-in-Windows-P) works fine. 
I want to use shown below code snippets

```
class A
{
  public :
  static int i = 1;

};
```

However, I want to pass this class instance to this call back function pointer described below

```
void Init(void (*Notify)(A *a, int, int,int),int arr[],
          A *a, value,int left,int right)
{

}
```

Comment: Could you post specific code lines that you fail to compile? It's unclear what you mean by saying "I want to pass this class instance to this call back function pointer".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Boost Bind directly to do this.  Your `Init` function requires a pointer to a free function having this signature:

```
void (*)(A *a, int, int, int)
```

So you could implement one like this:

```
void foo(A *a, int x, int y, int z)
{
    a->whatever(x, y, z);
}
```

You'd then call `Init(foo, ...)`.

But it will have to be a free function; the somewhat equivalent Boost Bind expression will not work:

```
boost::bind(&A::whatever, _1, _2, _3)
```

Why won't this work?  Because `Init` requires a free function, not e.g. a `boost::function<void(A*,int,int,int>)>` which would support `boost::bind`.